# Reading raw messages from Amazon SQS using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

By default, boto encodes messages with Base64 before the messages are sent to SQS. Example code:

```
conn = boto.connect_sqs('access_key_id', 'secret_key') 
q = conn.get_queue('myqueue')
m = Message()
m.set_body('hello!')
q.write(m)
```

By replacing Message() with RawMessage(), I can send raw messages to the queue without encoding. But how do I read messages from the queue without decoding? If I use the following code:

```
rs = q.get_messages(1)
if rs:
    m = rs[0]
    print m.get_body()
```

m.get_body() automatically returns the decoded result. Is there a way to retrieve raw messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of `boto.sqs.queue.Queue` has a `message_class` argument, which you could set to `RawMessage`. On the other hand, I don't see why it could ever make sense to not encode that data before transmitting it.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I use it for debugging because you can't view encoded message in AWS SQS console.

Comment: Late answer here - but for others - encoding the messages can take a solid 20%-30% of your message space. If you need that extra leeway for larger messages, not encoding can help.

Answer (score 14):

In case you are interested to just read the messages off SQS queue and the producer was someone else, you may start seeing garbage character when call get_messages().
See https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/831

Solution in this case again, is to

```
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
q.set_message_class(RawMessage)
```

Comment: This explains why I'm getting nonsense when I read messages sent to SQS from SNS.

Comment: I put the message in the Q with .NET AWSSDK using a string for the body.  Pulling it off in python with boto produces garbage unless you pull it off as a RawMessage. Good call!

Answer (score 7):

Actually `Message` class inherits from `RawMessage`, so it has all of it's methods.
One of these methods is:

**[`get_body_encoded()`](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.message.RawMessage.get_body_encoded)**

> *This method is really a semi-private method used by the Queue.write
>   method when writing the contents of the message to SQS. You probably
>   shouldn’t need to call this method in the normal course of events.*

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there's such a method.